# this object in Class Components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding the object `this` in class Components.

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      age: 30,
      names: {
        fn: 'Naruto',
        ln: 'Uzumaki'
      }
    };
    this.ref = this.state;
    console.log('constructor');
  }

    update = () => {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    };

    render() {
    console.log(Object.is(this.state, this.ref), this.state, this.ref);
    console.log(this.state.names === this.ref.names);
        return <div className="App">
      {this.state.count}
      <button onClick={this.update}>click</button>
      </div>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

**o/p after the initial render:**

```
constructor 
true
{count: 0, age: 30, names: Object}
{count: 0, age: 30, names: Object}
true
```

**o/p after the subsequent renders:**

```
false
{count: 1, age: 30, names: Object}
{count: 0, age: 30, names: Object}
true

false
{count: 2, age: 30, names: Object}
{count: 0, age: 30, names: Object}
true

false
{count: 3, age: 30, names: Object}
{count: 0, age: 30, names: Object}
true
```

Why the `this.ref` the points to `this.state` variable are different in each `render` after the initial one?
If the `Objects` are merged in by the `setState` call then `this.state` and `this.ref` must be pointing to the same object after each render, right? Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: React state is immutable. Calling this.setState creates a *new* this.state, it doesn't edit the old one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean React maintains its own state object and gives a new state after each render?

Comment: `Does that mean React maintains its own state object` They probably just do something like `this.state = {...this.state, ...updatedState}`. Ie, overwrite `this.state` with a new object.

Comment: @Vegeta can you mark this as answered? It gives me stack Overflow cred :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, `Object.is(this.state, this.ref)` is returning false after the first change.

This is because once 'setState' is called, the class's state gets set to a new saved 'state' object. This is why you can't update a class's state with `this.state.x = val.`

If you were to set this.ref=this.state after each set, the two objects WOULD remain the same.

Assume an assign of `object.state` will always copy what the class's state is **at that exact moment**